# How to redirect test result to txt file by ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, testunit

When your own test suite had executed, there were some results.
i want to keep thoes infomation in a txt file or html,
but i don't how to save those outputted message,
if anyone knows,please share with me, thanks in advance
the belowing code is my experiment, but it doesn't work.

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  'person')
require "test/unit"

filename = "logfile.txt"
$logfile = File.new(filename,"a")
open(logfile,'a') { |f| f << $stdout}

class PersonTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE = 'Nathaniel', 'Taldtretbott', 25

  def setup
    @person = Person.new(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE)
  end

  def test_first_name
    assert_equal "asv", @person.first_name,"try to compare"
  end

  def test_last_name
    assert_equal "Taldtretbott", @person.last_name
  end

  def test_full_name
    assert_equal FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME, @person.full_name
  end
end
```

Comment: Use the braces icon ({}) to fm your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do

```
ruby testfile.rb > text_output.txt
```

Comment: thanks very much. Is there any another way to redirect the output infomation?

Answer (score 1):

I had some time to try some testing on a solution. I managed to put it to work this way:

```
require 'test/unit'

STDOUT = $stdout = File.open("stdout.txt", "a+")
STDERR = $stderr = File.open("stderr.txt", "a+")

class AreasTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_ok
    puts "#{Time.now} Hello "
    a = 10
    assert_equal(a, 10)
  end


  def test_fail
    a = 9
    assert_equal(a, 10)
  end
end
```

It gives a warning cause STDOUT and STDERR were already initialized but just redirecting $stdout and $stderr does not work (works only for normal puts).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$stdout = $logfile
```

instead of:

```
open(logfile,'a') { |f| f << $stdout}
```

This means that you are redirecting the stdout to the file.